# How can I save the value typed by user in dropdown & use that in a editable combo of `org.eclipse.swt.widgets`?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have created one `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo` field which in editable.

`tableCombo = new Combo(cmposite, SWT.NONE);`

I stored some value in the `combo` at the time of creating the widgets.I want that if user write some value may be string  in the `combo` ,then it will save it the `combo` dropdown list & user should be able to select the given input.How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Just add a listener to the combo (e.g. on focus loss) which calls [`Combo.add(String)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Combo.html#add%28java.lang.String%29). See [this example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet289.java).